# A While Loop Condition In PHP

Tags: php, operators, conditional-statements

I have seen the following while loop condition in many examples and even I have used it in many times. I know how it works and how to use it. But as i code the condition here doesn't make any sense.

As I see the code, the condition is like it's always true. Just like *while(1)*. Because to the *mysql_fetch_assoc()*, the same data is passed is passed all the time. So the condition is a constant.

```
while($arr = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) 
{
      //other code
}
```

Now, where Am I Wrong ????

Comment: `$data` contains internal data you can't normally see, such as "last row that was fetched was #5". This data is used by `mysql_fetch_assoc` to return the next row or a NULL. So no, the condition is not constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each call to `mysql_fetch_assoc` gets *the next* row from the result set. If there is no row anymore it returns `false` and the loop terminates.

`$data` is a [resource](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) data type and will probably keep the state about which row was fetched last.
This is not so unusual, even arrays have an internal pointer to the current element which can be manipulated using certain array functions.

Comment: thanks, that's what i was confused about. It's just a frikin' function trick.

Answer (score 0):

From the [PHP website](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php), mysql_fetch_assoc "*Returns an associative array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or FALSE if there are no more rows.*"

Therefore, whenever there are still rows available, `mysql_fetch_assoc` will return an associated array of the row contents, will increment the pointer to the next row and the `while` loop will execute.

When there are no more rows `mysql_fetch_assoc` will return `FALSE` and the loop will break.

Also note that as of PHP 5.5.5 this function will be deprecated.

Comment: *"and will increment the array pointer to the next row"* ... `$data` is not an array though. Or do you have more information about how MySQL resource links are implemented?

Comment: My bad - have removed 'array'